# Add column for squares/cubes/etc for each column in numpy/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, regression

I’m trying to take a set of data that consists of N rows, and expand each row to include the squares/cube/etc of each column in that row (what power to go up to is determined by a variable j). The data starts out as a pandas DataFrame but can be turned into a numpy array.

For example:
If the row is [3,2] and j is 3, the row should be transformed to [3, 2, 9, 4, 27, 8]

I currently have a semi working version that consists of a bunch of nested for loops and is pretty ugly. I’m hoping for a cleaner way to make this transformation so things will be a bit easier for me to debug.

The behavior I’m looking for is basically the same as sklearns PolynomialFeature, but I’m trying to do it in numpy and or pandas only.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example DataFrame along with the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `concat` with `ignore_index` option to remove duplicate in column names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))

j = 3

pd.concat([df**i for i in range(1,j+1)], axis=1,ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2   3   4   5    6    7    8
0  0  1  2   0   1   4    0    1    8
1  3  4  5   9  16  25   27   64  125
2  6  7  8  36  49  64  216  343  512
```

Answer (score 2):

Use NumPy broadcasting for a vectorized solution -

```
In [66]: a = np.array([3,2])

In [67]: j = 3

In [68]: a**np.arange(1,j+1)[:,None]
Out[68]: 
array([[ 3,  2],
       [ 9,  4],
       [27,  8]])
```

And there's a NumPy builtin : [`np.vander`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html) -

```
In [142]: np.vander(a,j+1).T[::-1][1:]
Out[142]: 
array([[ 3,  2],
       [ 9,  4],
       [27,  8]])
```

Or with `increasing` flat set as `True` -

```
In [180]: np.vander(a,j+1,increasing=True).T[1:]
Out[180]: 
array([[ 3,  2],
       [ 9,  4],
       [27,  8]])
```